# Преобразование фурье

Tags: распознавание-речи

Написал программу, которая извлекает sample из Wav. В Wav файле есть 2 канала(стерео). Хочу применить преобразование фурье, но запутался в одном. Я не понимаю, как эти два семпла объединить в один и применить формулу прямого преобразования. X(k) = Sum(xn * e^-2*pi*k*n*i/N. Где xn - sample. Или я что то не понимаю.

Comment: Преобразование фурье работает для одного сигнала (мноно-канала), поэтому вы можете либо посчитать его для двух каналов, либо просто конвертировать источник в моно, используя среднее значение двух каналов.

Comment: @etki (|s1| + |s2|)/2 Так что ли?

Comment: Почти, просто сумма пополам, модуль брать не надо, потому что сигнал меняется от -1 до +1

Comment: @etki Спасибо большое

Comment: @etki сигнал меняется от -1 до 1, это какие его параметры меняются так?

Comment: Амплитуда. Если мы говорим в эээ машинных терминах, то обычно используют диапазон -32768...32767 для 16бит, но на самом деле это то же самое.

Comment: @etki а как разбить звук на frame?